# Java: What are the various available security settings for applets

Tags: java, security, sockets, permissions, applet

I have an applet that throws this exception when trying to communicate with the server (running on localhost). This problem is limited to Applets only - a POJO client is able to communicate with the exact same server without any problem.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net
.SocketPermission 127.0.0.1:9999 connect,resolve)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
```

My applet.policy file's contents is:

```
grant {
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

My question is what are the **other places where I need to modify my security settings** to grant an Applet more security settings?

Thank you.

---

EDIT: Further investigation has lead me to find that this problem only occurs on some machines - but not others. So it could be a machine level (global) setting that is causing this, rather than a application-specific setting such as the one in the applet.policy file.

---

EDIT: [Another SO question: Socket connection to originating server of an unsigned Java applet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850497/socket-connection-to-originating-server-of-an-unsigned-java-applet)
This seems to describe the exact same problem, and [Tom Hawtin - tackline 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850497/socket-connection-to-originating-server-of-an-unsigned-java-applet/850648#850648) provides the reason why (a security patch released that disallows applets from connecting to `localhost`). Bearing this in mind, how do I grant the applet the security settings such that in can indeed run on my machine. Also why does it run as-is on other machines but not mine?

Comment: Are you trying localhost, or 127.0.0.1?  I believe I used localhost in a previous project of mine, and it worked ok

Comment: @tim_yates Yup, I am using "localhost", which resolves to `127.0.0.1` internally. But "127.0.0.1" doesn't actually appear in my code if that is what you mean.

Comment: Have you tried signing your applet JAR file and see what happens?

Comment: If your applet code is loaded from localhost, it shouldn't be a problem. There is no need to remove the client's security for things like this.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - tackline The applet code is indeed loaded from localhost, so I remain baffled by this AccessControlException

Comment: @bguiz Is there any JavaScript involved? That has different rules.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - tackline Nope, its just a simple JApplet, pure Java.

Comment: @bguiz, have you tried signing your jar (http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/) and see if that solved your problem?

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman thank you very much for your comments - Please post it as an answer, and I'll give you the tick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing this: http://sunsolve.sun.com/search/document.do?assetkey=1-66-246387-1, it's clear that Applets run from localhost (without being deployed to a web server) **cannot** access localhost.

There is no workaround for this issue as indicated

> **4. Workaround**
>
> There is no workaround for this issue.
>   Please see the Resolution section
>   below.

My suggestion is as follows:

- Signing a Jar file to get more security privileges (http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/signindex.html)

It stipulates:

> Users who verify your signature can
>   grant your JAR-bundled software
>   security privileges that it wouldn't
>   ordinarily have.

- Running your applet from a web server (such as Tomcat) and accessing it locally through your browser.