# Unsigned applet socket JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, applet

With Java 1.6.0.22 i'm not able to open a socket to localhost, the applet is unsigned and is being loaded from the webserver http://localhost/myapplet

If i load it from my computer ip 192.168.1.x and open a socket to that ip it works

With a simple demo that only open a socket it works, but as soon as my applet use JavaScript to Java calls the socket not work.

If I add a crossdomain.xml file the socket works again.

If I allow only 127.0.0.1 it doesn't work

With 1.6.0.17 it works fine

That is similar to question 
[Socket connection to originating server of an unsigned Java applet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850497/socket-connection-to-originating-server-of-an-unsigned-java-applet)

But in my case i loading applet from a webserver not from local file system.

Comment: Sorry, but what's your actual question?

Comment: Why the socket cannot be open to localhost when using JavaScript, and. And why work when add the crossdomain.xml to my webserver root, i always in the same domain '127.0.0.1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via this user having a similar problem i found the relevant oracle bug

[access denied (java.net.SocketPermission 127.0.0.1:8080 connect,resolve)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135138/access-denied-java-net-socketpermission-127-0-0-18080-connect-resolve)

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/6u22releasenotes-176121.html

Answer (score 0):

Unsigned applets can only open connections to the host they were loaded from.

Comment: That is not truth, unsigned applets can open connection to other hosts if they provide a crossdomain.xml file, that was introduced in 1.6.0.10.

Comment: Your answer is unrelated to the original question, what i asked for is why connection to the same host fails when using JavaScript integration and success when it not, are there any additional restrictions for JavaScript and localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle knows of this Java problem that severely restricts use of Applets: A Security Vulnerability in the Java Runtime Environment may Allow Code Loaded From the Local Filesystem to Access LocalHost. The translation: if you wish to run Java Applets that talk to a server like Tomcat, you can’t do it with recent Java releases

And their solution is: There is no workaround for this issue.

And how long have they known of this problem? 03-Dec-2008, Bug Id 6704154

You can validate the above information at, https://identity.sun.com/amserver/UI/Login?org=self_registered_users&goto=http://sunsolve.sun.com/show.do?target=home

Comment: I loading the applet from a webserver not from filesystem, and Socket connection to localhost works, but if i use JSObject JavaScript integration the socket to localhost stop to works, if i add a crossdomain.xml file it works again.

Answer (score -1):

While the documentation says an applet can only open a connection to the host it was loaded from, with Tomcat 5, that statement is not true. I have an applet that invariably generates a, "AccessControlException:access denied (java.net.SocketPermission 66.167.210:80 connect, resolve" even though I've given socket permission to this URL. I'm still trying to solve this issue and am open to any recommendations.

Comment: that is unrelated to the original question